# RSA trick in email reply

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, public-key-encryption

A uses RSA encryption for her email. B ﬁnds an encrypted email to A: c = m^e mod n that he wants to know the plain text. B knows that when A replies to her email, **she always includes the text of the message she is responding to in the reply**.

Assume A only receives messages that are bit strings of length at most log n, which can be 
mapped to Zn.

Also assume that B cannot simply send c as his own email to A and expect a reply, but that A will respond to email messages other than c.

How can B learn m using only c, e, n and random values from Zn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#Attacks_against_plain_RSA):

> RSA has the property that the product
>   of two ciphertexts is equal to the
>   encryption of the product of the
>   respective plaintexts. That is m1^e m2^e≡(m1m2)^e (mod n) Because
>   of this multiplicative property a
>   chosen-ciphertext attack is possible.
>   E.g. an attacker, who wants to know
>   the decryption of a ciphertext c = m^e
>   (mod n) may ask the holder of the
>   private key to decrypt an
>   unsuspicious-looking ciphertext c' =
>   cr^e (mod n) for some value r chosen by
>   the attacker. Because of the
>   multiplicative property c' is the
>   encryption of mr (mod n). Hence, if
>   the attacker is successful with the
>   attack, he will learn mr (mod n) from
>   which he can derive the message m by
>   multiplying mr with the modular
>   inverse of r modulo n.

That's actually pretty neat, thanks for asking the question that lead me to learning this.
As for your question of 3020 vs 600, it's multiplicative; rarely are concatenations used in mathematics, since after all we should always be working independent of base.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the rough idea but some points are not clear for me. First, for the product property, do you mean `c1 = m1^e mod n, c2 = m2^e mode n, then c1c2 = (m1m2)^e mode n`? Or `c1 = m1^e mod n, c2 = (c1m2)^e mode n, then c2 = (m1m2)^e mode n`?  Second, what does the production really mean? For example, if m1 = 20, m2 = 30, is m1m2 = 20*30 = 600 or m1m2=2030?

Comment: It seems the ^ have been stripped when I copy pasted. Clarifying my answer